# My systemd Solr service will not enable. No error message

Tags: solr, systemd

Earlier today I was able to get a systemd definition working for solr.  Then I made an edit to the definition and tried to reload it, and now the service is somehow no longer enabled, and I can't enable it.  If I do...

```
systemctl enable solr.service
```

...there is no output. No error message.  But then if I do...

```
systemctl -l | grep solr
```

...there is nothing there.  It seems to be falling back on System V when I run "service solr start".  Solr starts, but it isn't using the systemd definition.

If I run "systemctl status solr.service", I see...

```
# systemctl status solr.service
? solr.service - Apache SOLR
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/solr.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2020-10-15 18:34:09 EDT; 15min ago
 Main PID: 44533 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Answer (score 1):

Evidently the service was enabled, but I needed a slightly different sequence of commands to start it.  I also seem to need the following in my systemd definition:

```
Type=forking
```

I don't think I needed that earlier, but it seems to be necessary now.  After each change to my solr.service file, I need to run "systemctl daemon-reload" and then restart solr.

I also needed to ensure solr was not already running (with System V), and then start it with systemctl, like so...

```
service solr stop
systemctl start solr
```

Then I could run "systemctl status solr.service" and get a better result...

```
# systemctl status solr.service
? solr.service - Apache SOLR
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/solr.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-10-15 19:27:34 EDT; 2min 49s ago
  Process: 78134 ExecStart=/opt/solr/bin/solr start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 78181 (java)
    Tasks: 55
   Memory: 2.1G
   CGroup: /system.slice/solr.service
           +-78181 java -server -Xms31g -Xmx31g -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=500 -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:G1MaxNewSizePer...
```

---

Separately, I don't know why I was getting no output from...

```
systemctl -l | grep solr
```

The systemctl command by itself should be equivalent to "systemctl list-units" and the -l flag is an alias for --all.  This should list known units, whether active or not.